# Como faço para somar duas strings em C#?

Tags: c#, string

Tenho um método que receberá duas strings e retornará a soma das mesmas em formato de string.

Utilizo string pois virão números de +-30 dígitos. Estou com problemas na hora de converter pra somar. :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como fala em converter para `ulong` vou partir do principio que as *strings* representam inteiros.

```
public string Somar(string numA, string numB)
{
    BigInteger bigA = BigInteger.Parse(numA);
    BigInteger bigB = BigInteger.Parse(numB);
    return BigInteger.Add(bigA, bigB).ToString();
}
```

Se quiser tratar *float* ou *double* troque *BigInteger* por *BigDecimal*.
Uma excepção do tipo *FormatException* será lançada se não for possível fazer o *Parse*.

Comment: Só falto um `()` no final do ToString né? :D

Answer (score 3):

Se estiver usando .Net Framework 4.0 ou maior pode usar o [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx). Só será necessário referenciar o seguinte assembly `System.Numerics`.

Comment: Utilizo o .NET 4.5.2, porém ele não encontra o BigInteger.

http://prntscr.com/7fvinq

Comment: @JonathanBarcela vc precisa adicionar a referência System.Numerics ao seu projeto.